# Issues with SKLEARN importing cross_validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am trying to play around with machine learning but I am having issues with sklearn and importing cross_validation. I keep getting error messages saying

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'cross_validation' from 'sklearn' (C:\Python3.7\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py)
```

When I check pip list, it is definitely there; showing sklearn 0.0. There seems to be no other version of sklearn apart from 0.0.

Someone please help.

I am using sentdex's youtube tutorial series on regression for this code.

```
import pandas as pd

import sklearn

from sklearn import preprocessing, cross_validation,svm

from sklearn import LinearRegression
```

Comment: `from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate` it has been moved.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer lies directly in the relevant [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html)

Comment: Welcome to SO; please see why [research must be done to ask a good question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/)

Answer (score 0):

That is because Sklearn doesn't have any cross_validation module. 
Try using:

```
from sklearn import model_selection
```

The cross_validation model has been deprecated.